# Best way to query a data dictionary in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For a project I'm setting up, I need a very dynamic data structure. I'm going to store records for which I don't have a defintion. One record could consist of 5 columns, another might be 10.

To support this, I want to use a table with the following columns:

ResultId
RecordId
RecordTypeId
Key
Value

This supports all possible schemes, but I have do a few questions.

- Is this the best approach or are there better options I've missed?
- What's a good way to query this and get my records out the way they got in? I have definitions stored in a different table which tell me which columns are stored per recordtype. I've seen the PIVOT statement which requires a dynamic buildp since you need to provide the fields in an array style (though that could be fed by a stored procedure I guess)
- How will performance hold up for large numbers of records?
- Is it handy to use things like EF / Linq?

This will be coded in .NET 4, C# with a SQL2008R2 Express back-end. I'm looking for some best practices.

Update! To clarify a bit more: I need to store resultsets of data from different, unknown, queries. I don't know how many query definitions there will be or how they will look like. The data in this database is only used for processing. Users won't even know these tables exist, there will be no input, there won't be any reports or any data hitting the screen in any way. The resultsets are used for comparison against other resultsets, all through code. What I need is a highly dynamic way to store these records which keeps performing when there's a great number of records involved.

Another option I thought of is:

ResultId
RecordId
field1 (sql_variant)
field2 (sql_variant)
field3 (sql_variant)
field4 (sql_variant)
...

Is this a better idea?

Comment: How does the user create the record and how will the data be maintained?

Comment: This is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really terrible data structure that will create tons of issues.

Comment: @Mark: the user doesn't actually create a record, a record is a result of a query on another database. And there will be multiple queries with different definitions

Comment: So why not create a new table to hold the results so use the RDBMS as the data dictionary as it is designed to be (or for many ones use remote tables)

Comment: @JNK ok, but what would be better? Another approach I know of is creating a number of float, varchar, int, etc. fields and map the results to those fields based upon the datatype. Going typed all the way isn't an options because I just don't know what the results will look like.

Comment: Aaahhh, the good ol' meta DB....

Comment: @Mark I'm not so sure about the retrieving part. Creating tables on the fly (I would have to create one per query definition) would leave me with a lot of tables without keys or indexes. Huge performance killer?

Comment: I bet that would perform better than your suggestion

Comment: @Mark, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Why use a database for this?  Something else (anything else, really) would be better suited.  XML, for instance.

Comment: If you don't want to query it for reporting and it's not shown to the user and you simply want to store records (objects?) and get them back the way they were why would you split them up in key/value pairs at all? Why not simply serialize the objects and store them somewhere (xml file, nosql db or if you really want to in a _single_ xml field in the database)?

Comment: Using an XML file doesn't sound like a bad idea actually. Maybe I was a bit too focussed on databases that I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Jasper - what is the business issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am considering leaving my contact details here so that you can call me when you have problems, because this structure will cause problems! Could make a quick buck or two.... After a few thousand records a stone tablet will be faster to get information out of

Comment: @Mark: the business case is as follows: I have a database of a third party application. I need to get aggregated sets of data (mostly like views) from that database and sync those to an online system. My client software has to be able to sync different databases based upon a variable set of queries I define per client. It's too costly to do a complete sync each time, so I have to check which records were added, modified or deleted. Therefore I need a temp store which I can compare with the query result on each sync to get the in between changes. Changing the clients database is a no-no.

Comment: This is a good question, because many people who are new to database design might like to hear the explanations of the more experienced as to why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 15):

I know this does not answer the question but I could not refrain from posting (although I will most likely get down voted). It illustrates the point. Straight from The Daily WTF:

> It was my second interview and it opened pretty conversationally.
>
> "We're thinking of storing table names and columns in the database,"
>   the interview said, "it's an idea floating around."
>
> I replied, "Instead of creating tables and storing the data depending
>   on how it's structured?"
>
> "Yeah!" his eyes lit up, "then we don't have to define structures or
>   any other mess!"
>
> I wondered it it was some sort of test. "How would you do reports?
>   Would it not be awkward?"
>
> "We could do that from the front end."
>
> "Maybe," I said, "but wouldn't it require a lot of code? And it'd be
>   incredibly slow."
>
> "Not if we used hashtables!"
>
> "Okay... what about data integrity, foreign keys, that sort of thing?"
>
> He was getting more defensive, "it'd be all from the front end."
>
> "I suppose, but this would all require an exorbitant amount of code
>   with all sorts of complex SQL queries. It's not that bad to change a
>   database if you—"
>
> "No," he interrupted, "we would use a data access layer to abstract it
>   to normalized data structures."
>
> "You mean... like tables?"
>
> Two days later, my recruiter told me that they declined me as a
>   candidate because I wasn't technical enough. Though I do wonder if
>   they ever implemented their meta-database implementation, I'm glad
>   I'll never know.

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Three-for-Three,-Recursion-Threads,-and-Wrong-Answer.aspx

Comment: I get your point, but your story makes a couple of assumptions which arent true. Users arent going to enter any data into these tables. There won't be any foreign keys or other connections whatsoever and there will definitely won't be reporting and stuff like that. The data in these tables will never hit the screen in any way. Please take that into account, rethink and provide me with an answer that actually helps.

Comment: I understand that. It's just to illustrate that meta DBs are never the answer. You should go by @Mark's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the table [syscolumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) and related ones. This looks rather like what you describe. But with many years of work Sybase and Microsoft have come up with a way that is probably more efficient than you can come up with.

To make use of this for each different set of columns in a report create a new table an import the data - the database will manage the access for you. You comment on no indicies on these tables - but where do you hold that information in your schema - if you had that data then just as easy to create indices on these SQL tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know all your requirements but if you simply have extra dynamic fields, you might want to take a look at XML data type in SQL Server: [Implementing XML in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx). This will allow you to write SQL queries against the XML data type.

By the way what you are suggesting is not completely crazy idea. There are many well-known document management systems that used a very similar dynamic schema implementation. To query the data you need to construct a rather complex queries. In your case you simply group records by record id and that you give you all record columns.

Before you go ahead to implement any of that, think twice whether there is a possibility to implement this using a static schema. This will make your life much easier (when implementing but especially when debugging your application). Take a look maybe at [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) or [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) (these are static schemas that you can extend using "inheritance" at design time).