# Pivoting rows into columns dynamically in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I have the following Oracle 10g table called _kv:

```
select * from _kv

ID       K       V
----     -----   -----
  1      name    Bob
  1      age     30
  1      gender  male
  2      name    Susan
  2      status  married
```

I'd like to turn my keys into columns using plain SQL (not PL/SQL) so that the resulting table would look something like this:

```
ID       NAME    AGE    GENDER  STATUS
----     -----   -----  ------  --------
  1      Bob      30     male 
  2      Susan                   married
```

- The query should have as many columns as unique `K`s exist in the table (there aren't that many)
- There's no way to know what columns may exist before running the query.
- I'm trying to avoid running an initial query to programatically build the final query.
- The blank cells may be nulls or empty strings, doesn't really matter.
- I'm using Oracle 10g, but an 11g solution would also be ok.

There are a plenty of examples out there for when you know what your pivoted columns may be called, but I just can't find a generic pivoting solution for Oracle.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear God, is that a... meta DB??

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340422/best-way-to-query-a-data-dictionary-in-sql/7340554#7340554

Comment: I always found humor in reading this about the 'entity attribute value' tables: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2314483800346542969

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my design (and the _kv table is an example)... I need to generate some realtime reports from that table, and any attempt to filter or order by is just driving me nuts.

Comment: wow, if you wanted a key value pair db, you're overpaying tremendously using Oracle.  Look into Berkeley db (still free, but ironically controlled by Oracle ;).  Better yet, redesign that sucker... at all costs. best of luck

Comment: I think that this clause: "I'm trying to avoid running an initial query to programatically build the final query." is going to be the difficult part to overcome.  I think that @Dave is correct in their recommendation, but you may be constrained to a 'get me my columns' query then a dynamic pivot build off of that) -->hopefully someone proves me wrong - I just cannot see how you will be able to avoid that!

Answer (score 36):

Oracle 11g provides a `PIVOT` operation that does what you want.

**Oracle 11g solution**

```
select * from
(select id, k, v from _kv) 
pivot(max(v) for k in ('name', 'age', 'gender', 'status')
```

*(Note: I do not have a copy of 11g to test this on so I have not verified its functionality)*

I obtained this solution from: http://orafaq.com/wiki/PIVOT

**EDIT -- pivot xml option (also Oracle 11g)**
Apparently there is also a `pivot xml` option for when you do not know all the possible column headings that you may need. (see the **XML TYPE** section near the bottom of the page located at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
select * from
(select id, k, v from _kv) 
pivot xml (max(v)
for k in (any) )
```

*(Note: As before I do not have a copy of 11g to test this on so I have not verified its functionality)*

**Edit2:** Changed `v` in the `pivot` and `pivot xml` statements to `max(v)` since it is supposed to be aggregated as mentioned in one of the comments. I also added the `in` clause which is not optional for `pivot`. Of course, having to specify the values in the `in` clause defeats the goal of having a completely dynamic pivot/crosstab query as was the desire of this question's poster.

Comment: the `pivot(v for k)` part is not working in 11g, the `for` needs an `in`, and I don't know what to put into that `in` clause

Comment: @dave - The PIVOT operation only works with a fixed set of columns.  Your query can't suddenly return more columns because an additional row is added to the table.

Comment: @JustinCave , @ojosilva I thought that the `in` clause may be optional for if you wanted to limit the columns to specific values and that it could be left out if all values were wanted. Apparently there is a `pivot xml` option that deals with this ( see the updated answer ).

Comment: the xml pivot worked adding an aggregation on v: `(max(v) for k in (any))`, but the result is xml in a clob column called `K_XML` - not quite what I need.

Answer (score 7):

To deal with situations where there are a possibility of multiple values (v in your example), I use `PIVOT` and `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT id, k, v
  FROM _kv 
)
PIVOT 
(
  LISTAGG(v ,',') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY k) 
  FOR k IN ('name', 'age','gender','status')
)
ORDER BY id;
```

Since you want dynamic values, use dynamic SQL and pass in the values determined by running a select on the table data before calling the pivot statement.

Answer (score 5):

Happen to have a task on pivot. Below works for me as tested just now on 11g:

```
select * from
(
  select ID, COUNTRY_NAME, TOTAL_COUNT from ONE_TABLE 
) 
pivot(
  SUM(TOTAL_COUNT) for COUNTRY_NAME in (
    'Canada', 'USA', 'Mexico'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, dynamically pivot using `pivot xml` again needs to be parsed. We have another way of doing this by storing the column names in a variable and passing them in the dynamic sql as below.

Consider we have a table like below.

[image]

If we need to show the values in the column `YR` as column names and the values in those columns from `QTY`, then we can use the below code.

```
declare
  sqlqry clob;
  cols clob;
begin
  select listagg('''' || YR || ''' as "' || YR || '"', ',') within group (order by YR)
  into   cols
  from   (select distinct YR from EMPLOYEE);


  sqlqry :=
  '      
  select * from
  (
      select *
      from EMPLOYEE
  )
  pivot
  (
    MIN(QTY) for YR in (' || cols  || ')
  )';

  execute immediate sqlqry;
end;
/
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: have question on ``listagg('''' || YR || ''' as "' || YR || '"', ',')  ``. why not ``listagg(YR, ',')``? what does ``'''' ||`` do in there?

Comment: It gives all columns in single row with comma separated values. CLOBS @MichaelLi