# PIVOT or PIVOT XML without listing the columns explicitly on Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, pivot, pivot-xml

I am working on PL/SQL Developer v10 on Oracle 11g database.
The idea is instead of writing 145 columns listed in `PIVOT` statement write an `Pivot XML` and get data from there, [I am working on a basis of this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle) as I have never done PIVOT XML before on Oracle so my expectations might be wrong

```
select * from (
                    select
                      tqs.transactiondetailid as transactiondetailid,
                      q.productid as productid,
                      tqs.answer as QAnswer,
                      regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(WIF|DT|WT)[([:digit:]|.)]*') as QDesc,
                      tqs.transactionversion as transactionversion
                    from TRANSACTIONDETAILQS tqs
                    inner join question q on q.questionid = tqs.questionid and (
                          q.questiondescription like 'DT%' 
                          or  q.questiondescription like 'WT%' 
                          or q.questiondescription like 'WIF%')
    ) pivot xml(
    min(QAnswer) for QDesc in (
    select regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(WIF|DT|WT)[([:digit:]|.)]*') as r from question q
    where regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(WIF|DT|WT)[([:digit:]|.)]*') IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

in XML column does not return any data they all are empty, however following statement where I list columns explicitly works just fine

```
select * from (
                    select
                      tqs.transactiondetailid as transactiondetailid,
                      q.productid as productid,
                      tqs.answer as QAnswer,
                      regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(WIF|DT|WT)[([:digit:]|.)]*') as QDesc,
                      tqs.transactionversion as transactionversion
                    from TRANSACTIONDETAILQS tqs
                    inner join question q on q.questionid = tqs.questionid and (
                          q.questiondescription like 'DT%' 
                          or  q.questiondescription like 'WT%' 
                          or q.questiondescription like 'WIF%')
    ) pivot (
    min(QAnswer) for QDesc in (
    'DT01.','DT02.','WT01.')
    )
```

**How to pivot without listing the columns explicitly?**

Comment: not certain, but your `regexp_substr(q.questiondescription,'(WIF|DT|WT)...` may be wrong. What happens if you reduce the complexity, and try to output just one column name as match, before trying to get all of them? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter 9 months later I figured out where the problem lies, see update. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I boiled it down to the problem of

```
min(QAnswer) for QDesc In (
    select 'DT01.','DT02.','WT01.' from dual )
)
```

not working, but

```
min(QAnswer) for QDesc In (
    'DT01.','DT02.','WT01.')
)
```

working fine.

One way to do this is [create dynamic PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS626) but I don't have enough courage to do this.