# Unpivot columns into rows (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, unpivot

much like this original SO [Pivoting rows into columns dynamically in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle)

but i would like to do the opposite

how can i get

```
 ID       NAME    AGE    GENDER  STATUS
----     -----   -----  ------  --------
  1      Bob      30     male 
  2      Susan                   married
```

into this

```
ID       K       V
----     -----   -----
  1      name    Bob
  1      age     30
  1      gender  male
  2      name    Susan
  2      status  married
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `unpivot`.

```
select * from t 
unpivot (
          v for k in ("NAME","AGE","GENDER","STATUS")
        ) u
```

You may have a type mismatch if the age column is an integer. In that case convert it to a character before unpivoting.

```
select *
from (select id,name,to_char(age) age,gender,status from t) t 
unpivot (
         v for k in ("NAME","AGE","GENDER","STATUS")
        ) u
```