# Oracle: How to transform two tables into a combination matrix

Tags: excel, oracle

I have tables that represent menus in such a way that one menu contains another, but not the other way around.

i.e.

```
Menu_A
  |-Menu_1
  |-Menu_2
  |-Menu_3
  |    :
Menu_B
  |-Menu_1
  |-Menu_2
  |-Menu_4
  |    :
Menu_C
  |-Menu_4
  |-Menu_5
  |-Menu_6

 -----------------
| Menu_A | Menu_1|                     
------------------
| Menu_A | Menu_2|
------------------
| Menu_A | Menu_3|          
------------------
| Menu_B | Menu_1|
------------------
| Menu_B | Menu_2|              
------------------
   :
```

Is there some way to transform this table into something looking like one below(eventually) maybe with the help of Excel if necessary?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|        | Menu_1 | Menu_2 | Menu_3 | Menu_4 | Menu_5 | Menu_6 |  
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu_A |   ○    |   ○    |   ○    |   × 　　|   ×  　|   ×    |  
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Menu_B |   ○    |   ○    |   ×    |   ○ 　　|   ×  　|   ×    |     
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
    :
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting rows into columns dynamically in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle)

Comment: It does not seem to apply to my case...

Comment: It exactly applies to your case. All you have to do it put NVL2 on the pivoted columns at the end.

Comment: would you provide some example?