# how to transpose and pivot in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

i am trying to flip the data from a table , here is a screenshot to explain how it looks.
[on the left we have database table and on right how i want to derive it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QwBg.png)

i have so far tried using pivot, and case statements but was not able to get the view i need, please guide

Answer (score 1):

This is typically a task that is performed in the presentation-layer and not in the database.

---

If you must do it in SQL then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   shift_t
PIVOT (
  MAX(shift)
  FOR shift_date IN (
    DATE '2022-07-01' AS "07/01/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-02' AS "07/02/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-03' AS "07/03/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-04' AS "07/04/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-05' AS "07/05/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-06' AS "07/06/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-07' AS "07/07/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-08' AS "07/08/2022",
    DATE '2022-07-09' AS "07/09/2022"
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | LOCATION | NAME | 07/01/2022 | 07/02/2022 | 07/03/2022 | 07/04/2022 | 07/05/2022 | 07/06/2022 | 07/07/2022 | 07/08/2022 | 07/09/2022 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | HYD | Rose | C | W | W | C | C | C | C | C | W |

*Note: You must hard-code the date values. They cannot be provided dynamically using a `PIVOT` statement. If you want a dynamic pivot then look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7730111/1509264) (and then ignore it and perform the task in the presentation-layer and not in SQL).*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f459d3860a290ad41447eed3b761fb36)*