How to get sum of certain values in a column and also the sum of all the rows in Oracle SQL?
I have 3 tables that I want to give a summary of in an SSRS report. Im having some issues forming the stored procedure of how to go about this.Here is a rough example of what I am thinking to do. I want to loop through all the countries which has a code that matches the first 2 digits of the C.CASE_ID. Hopefully this will give me the format of "01-France".
The following below are columns within PERSON.T_PERSON P table. I am having some issues figuring out how to find the sum of numerous "Red" or "Blue" within a column.
My DB will have something like this:
FCB - Red, Red, Blue, NA
FCT - Blue, Blue, NA, NA
FCA - Purple, Pink, NA, Pink

FCB = Favorite Color as Baby
FCT = Favorite Color as Teen
FCA = Favorite Color as Adult

FOR X IN (SELECT  M.CDE_KEY , M.DESC COUNTRY
FROM  MASTER.TABLE_VALUES M
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('COL1'))
LOOP
SELECT FCB, FCT, FCA FROM PERSON.T_PERSON P, PERSON.T_CASE_PERSON C 
WHERE P.IDN_INDIV = C.IDN_INDIV
AND SUBSTRING((LPAD(C.CASE_ID,6,0),0,2) = X.CDE_KEY;

Cursor - M.CDE_KEY || '-' || M.DESC As COUNTRY, SUM ("Red"), 
SUM("Blue"), SUM("NA") etc..
END LOOP



Provide sample data as markdown table. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Perhaps you should explore Oracle PIVOT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle

Are the above images showing sample table data or the expected result(s)? A [mcve] is supposed to include both anyway.

Yes I included an image. Are you able to view it?

Assuming your data could be similar to this:
WITH      --  S a m p l e    D a t a : 
    T_PERSON AS
      ( Select 1 as IDN_INDIV, 'Red' as FCB, 'Blue' as FCT, 'Purple' as FCA From Dual Union All 
        Select 2,              'Red',        'Blue',        'Pink'          From Dual Union All 
        Select 3,              'Blue',       'NA',          'NA'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 4,              'NA',         'Red',         'Pink'          From Dual Union All
        --
        Select 1,              'NA',         'White',       'Pink'          From Dual Union All 
        Select 2,              'Blue',       'Green',       'NA'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 3,              'NA',         'NY',          'Black'         From Dual Union All
        --
        Select 2,              'Red',        'Blue',        'NA'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 3,              'Red',        'NA',          'Green'         From Dual Union All 
        Select 4,              'Brown',      'Green',       'NA'            From Dual Union All
        --
        Select 1,              'Pink',       'Blue',        'Blue'          From Dual Union All 
        Select 3,              'Brown',      'NA',          'NA'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 4,              'NA',         'Red',         'Pink'          From Dual Union All
        --
        Select 1,              'Red',        'Blue',        'Pink'          From Dual Union All 
        Select 2,              'Blue',       'Green',       'NA'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 4,              'White',      'Na',          'Black'         From Dual
      ),
    T_CASE_PERSON AS
      ( Select 1 as IDN_INDIV, '01-aaa' as CASE_ID From Dual Union All 
        Select 2,              '02-bbb'            From Dual Union All 
        Select 3,              '03-ccc'            From Dual Union All
        Select 4,              '04-ddd'            From Dual 
      ), 
    TABLE_VALUES  AS
      ( Select 'COL1' as TABLE_NAME, '01' as CDE_KEY, 'France' as DESCRIPT From Dual Union All
        Select 'COL1',               '02',            'America'            From Dual Union All
        Select 'COL1',               '03',            'India'              From Dual Union All
        Select 'COL1',               '04',            'Wales'              From Dual
      ), 

... one option could be to use Oracle MODEL clause to get all the colors in three groups prepared for summation ...
    grid AS
      ( Select    *
        From    ( Select     Row_Number() Over(Partition By m.CDE_KEY Order By p.FCB, p.FCT, p.FCA) as RN_COUNTRY,
                             m.CDE_KEY || '-' || m.DESCRIPT as COUNTRY,
                             p.FCB, p.FCT, p.FCA 
                  From       TABLE_VALUES m
                  Inner Join T_CASE_PERSON c ON(m.CDE_KEY = SubStr(c.CASE_ID, 1, 2))
                  Left  Join T_PERSON p ON(p.IDN_INDIV = c.IDN_INDIV)
                  Where      m.TABLE_NAME = 'COL1'
                  Order By   m.CDE_KEY || '-' || m.DESCRIPT
                )
          MODEL    Partition By ( COUNTRY )
                   Dimension By ( RN_COUNTRY, FCB, FCT, FCA )
                   Measures  ( 0 as RED_FCB, 0 as BLUE_FCB, 0 as GREEN_FCB, 0 as PINK_FCB, 0 as OTHER_FCB, 0 as NA_FCB, 
                               0 as RED_FCT, 0 as BLUE_FCT, 0 as GREEN_FCT, 0 as PINK_FCT, 0 as OTHER_FCT, 0 as NA_FCT, 
                               0 as RED_FCA, 0 as BLUE_FCA, 0 as GREEN_FCA, 0 as PINK_FCA, 0 as OTHER_FCA, 0 as NA_FCA )
            RULES ( RED_FCB[ANY, 'Red', ANY, ANY] = 1, 
                    BLUE_FCB[ANY, 'Blue', ANY, ANY] = 1,
                    GREEN_FCB[ANY, 'Green', ANY, ANY] = 1,
                    PINK_FCB[ANY, 'Pink', ANY, ANY] = 1,
                    OTHER_FCB[ANY, ANY, ANY, ANY] = Case When CV(FCB) Not In('Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Pink', 'NY') Then 1 Else 0 End,
                    NA_FCB[ANY, 'NA', ANY, ANY] = 1,
                    --
                    RED_FCT[ANY, ANY, 'Red', ANY] = 1, 
                    BLUE_FCT[ANY, ANY, 'Blue', ANY] = 1,
                    GREEN_FCT[ANY, ANY, 'Green', ANY] = 1,
                    PINK_FCT[ANY, ANY, 'Pink', ANY] = 1,
                    OTHER_FCT[ANY, ANY, ANY, ANY] = Case When CV(FCT) Not In('Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Pink', 'NY') Then 1 Else 0 End,
                    NA_FCT[ANY, ANY, 'NA', ANY] = 1,
                    --
                    RED_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, 'Red'] = 1, 
                    BLUE_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, 'Blue'] = 1,
                    GREEN_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, 'Green'] = 1,
                    PINK_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, 'Pink'] = 1,
                    OTHER_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, ANY] = Case When CV(FCA) Not In('Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Pink', 'NY') Then 1 Else 0 End,
                    NA_FCA[ANY, ANY, ANY, 'NA'] = 1
                  )
      )

... now use UNION to get total row for all countries and a row per country
--    M a i n    S Q L :
  Select     '00-All Countries' as COUNTRY, 
             Sum(RED_FCB) as RED_FCB, Sum(BLUE_FCB) as BLUE_FCB, Sum(GREEN_FCB) as GREEN_FCB, 
             Sum(PINK_FCB) as PINK_FCB, Sum(OTHER_FCB) as OTHER_FCB, Sum(NA_FCB) as NA_FCB,
             --
             Sum(RED_FCT) as RED_FCT, Sum(BLUE_FCT) as BLUE_FCT, Sum(GREEN_FCB) as GREEN_FCT, 
             Sum(PINK_FCT) as PINK_FCT, Sum(OTHER_FCT) as OTHER_FCT, Sum(NA_FCB) as NA_FCT,
             --
             Sum(RED_FCA) as RED_FCA, Sum(BLUE_FCA) as BLUE_FCA, Sum(GREEN_FCA) as GREEN_FCA, 
             Sum(PINK_FCA) as PINK_FCA, Sum(OTHER_FCA) as OTHER_FCA, Sum(NA_FCA) as NA_FCA
  From       grid
UNION ALL
  Select     COUNTRY, 
             Sum(RED_FCB) as RED_FCB, Sum(BLUE_FCB) as BLUE_FCB, Sum(GREEN_FCB) as GREEN_FCB, 
             Sum(PINK_FCB) as PINK_FCB, Sum(OTHER_FCB) as OTHER_FCB, Sum(NA_FCB) as NA_FCB,
             --
             Sum(RED_FCT) as RED_FCT, Sum(BLUE_FCT) as BLUE_FCT, Sum(GREEN_FCB) as GREEN_FCT, 
             Sum(PINK_FCT) as PINK_FCT, Sum(OTHER_FCT) as OTHER_FCT, Sum(NA_FCB) as NA_FCT,
             --
             Sum(RED_FCA) as RED_FCA, Sum(BLUE_FCA) as BLUE_FCA, Sum(GREEN_FCA) as GREEN_FCA, 
             Sum(PINK_FCA) as PINK_FCA, Sum(OTHER_FCA) as OTHER_FCA, Sum(NA_FCA) as NA_FCA
  From       grid
  Group By   COUNTRY
  Order By   COUNTRY

/*      R e s u l t :
COUNTRY             RED_FCB   BLUE_FCB  GREEN_FCB   PINK_FCB  OTHER_FCB     NA_FCB    RED_FCT   BLUE_FCT  GREEN_FCT   PINK_FCT  OTHER_FCT     NA_FCT    RED_FCA   BLUE_FCA  GREEN_FCA   PINK_FCA  OTHER_FCA     NA_FCA
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
00-All Countries          5          3          0          1          7          4          2          5          0          0          5          4          0          1          1          5          9          6
01-France                 2          0          0          1          1          1          0          3          0          0          1          1          0          1          0          2          1          0
02-America                2          2          0          0          0          0          0          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          1          3          3
03-India                  1          1          0          0          2          1          0          0          0          0          3          1          0          0          1          0          3          2
04-Wales                  0          0          0          0          4          2          2          0          0          0          1          2          0          0          0          2          2          1    */

