# SQL query - Group By doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "Answer" like this:

```
Id, Registration_id, attendee_id, question_id, answer
12   Reg02                1             1        Paul
13   Reg02                1             2        Smith
14   Reg03                2             1        Rachel
15   Reg03                2             2        Silva
```

My query is:

```
Select attendee_id, answer
From wp_events_answer;
```

As a result I obtain this:

```
attendee_id  answer
    1         Paul
    1         Smith
    2         Rachel      
    2         Silva
```

But i'd like to have this:

```
 attendee_id  FirstName   Name
    1         Paul        Smith
    2         Rachel      Silva
```

I added `Group By attendee_id`. But it still doesn't work. As a result it displays only this:

```
 attendee_id    FirstName
 1              Paul
 2              Rachel
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I think this group by is working fine...

Comment: What you want is not the feature of group by

Comment: You cannot group by one column and select other non-aggregated column values.  I think mySql lets you, but the results you get will be random at best.

Comment: You need to make two queries, filter by question_id and join by attendee_id.

Comment: Smells like meta DB to me. Sigh... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7340554/570191

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a group, you need a self-join.

```
SELECT f.attendee_id, f.answer as FirstName, l.answer as Name
FROM wp_events_answer f
    JOIN wp_events_answer l ON f.attendee_id = l.attendee_id
WHERE f.question_id = 1 AND l.question_id = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have multiple rows from a table to show up in the result you need to join the table with itself.

```
select fn.attendee_id, fn.answer as FirstName, ln.answer as lastName FROM  wp_events_answer as fn INNER JOIN wp_events_answer as ln WHERE (fn.attendee_id = ln.attendee_id) and (fn.question_id = 1) and (ln.question_id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select 
  attendee_id, 
  group_concat(answer ORDER BY Id
               SEPERATOR ' ')
from wp_events_answer
group by attendee_id
```