# Column generation from table data with a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following tables:

Table A

```
Field Name  Field Value
Column1 Column1value
Column2 Column2value
Column3 Column3value
Column4 Column4value
```

Table B

```
Column1     Column2         Column3      Column4
Column1value  Column2value    Column3value   Column4value
```

How do I write a query to generate Table B from Table A?

Comment: Aahhh the good ol' meta DB.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7340554/570191

Comment: You are missing one thing in your meta DB TableA: what field groups the "pseudo-columns" together, so that you know the data belongs to a single entity. Meaning: how do you know that lastname Smith and Fist name James belong to entity James Smith?

Comment: Adrian, I was assuming this is all for just one group in this example.  It looks like best thing to do is let the Data Access Layer generate Table B.  Would be interesting to see if its possible to write a query to do this.  Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

If you need, using the next query you can get the column names from TableA:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    syscolumns 
WHERE
    id = (SELECT id  FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U' and NAME='TableA')
```

but if you just want to copy TableA to TableB, use the

```
SELECT 
*
INTO TableB
FROM TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SELECT INTO` and the resulting `TableB` below will have the same data and column types as the source table:

```
SELECT 
    Column1value, 
    Column2value, 
    Column3value, 
    Column4value
INTO TableB
FROM TableA
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if there are new columns, then the query would not work.  The columns need to be generated from TableA.  I don't think its possible using a query.