# How to optimize this complicated EAV MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, optimization, entity-attribute-value

Is it possible to optimize this query I have written

I've created a sort of dynamic virtual database to give my users the ability to add custom fields without affecting the database structure. Here is a very simplified view of the stucture so far.

```
tables         | columns
```

---

```
db_cases       | caseid
db_structure   | fieldname
db_data        | fieldname, data, caseid
db_names       | nameid
```

- We can create a new field by adding a row to db_structure
- Any data we wish to record is recorded to db_data.
- Names are stored in db_names and the name_id is stored in db_data

I am trying to output the cases to a html table

Hopefully the rest is self explanatory, you can see how unefficient it is. Can I do the same thing via joins?

```
SELECT 
case_id,
(SELECT data_field_value 
 FROM db_data 
 WHERE data_case_id = case_id AND data_field_name = 'casestatus'
) AS casestatus,
(SELECT forename_company 
 FROM db_names 
 WHERE name_id = (SELECT data_field_value 
                  FROM db_data 
                  WHERE data_case_id = case_id AND data_field_name = 'client1'
                 )
) AS client1_forename_company
FROM db_cases
```

Thanks

Comment: I would start by indenting it and making it understandable.

Comment: A dynamic database? So you're laying your own database semantics on top of an SQL database? Scary... http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx

Comment: Start by deleting it.

Comment: @MarcB Just sounds like SharePoint (lists) ... no big deal ;-) (Actually, SP changes the underlying table schema and maintains a mapping of internal/pretty/database column names.)

Comment: This is a perfect example of a really nasty EAV style structure. Bin it before it bins you!

Comment: Have you tried doing an EXPLAIN on it?

Comment: Aaahhh, the good ol' meta DB... http://stackoverflow.com/a/7340554/570191

Comment: @pst - fair comment. EAV certainly has its uses but sadly it is often poorly implemented and inappropriate for the given use case.

Comment: @nnichols further to my comment to tomas' answer, can anyone recommend an aternative concept which allows users to add their own fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Chibuzo is right. Start by deleting it :-)) But before, play with it a little, it's a good brain excercise, like chess or something :-)

```
select 
    case_id,
    d_status.data_field_value as case_status,
    d_client1_name.forename_company as client1_forename_company
from db_cases 
        join db_data as d_status 
            on d_status.data_case_id = case_id 
               AND d_status.data_field_name = 'casestatus'
        join db_data as d_client1
            on d_client1.data_case_id = case_id 
               AND d_client1.data_field_name = 'client1'
        join db_names as d_client1_name
            on d_client1_name.name_id = d_client1.data_field_value
```

I would expect these direct joins without subqueries to be much more efficient, though you'll have to test it - there are often surprises in optimizations.

Comment: Thanks Tomas this works a treat and is blitzing through the query now, however I can't ignore the recommendations on this thread that EAV is not a good idea. Other than the amount of code needed to maintain such a database (which is already done) can I ask why such a model is highly frowned on? Scaling?

Comment: @amof, so you say it is actually much more faster than the original query? How much?

Comment: originally I couldnt run the query over 2000 cases and 1 field, it was timing out after 30seconds, now I am able to run the query over 2000 cases and 10 fields - its practically instant. What alternatives are there to my model at the moment?

Comment: @amof - Storing data of differing types in a single generic VARCHAR is inefficient. EAV, espcially when implemented like this, does not scale well. If the field is going to be densely populated it makes more sense to modify the underlying table directly. You will still need to properly implement some kind of extension to the native data dictionary. Depending on your use case 6NF may be a suitable approach for your user defined fields. If you search SO for "EAV 6NF performance" you will find some detailed answers to similar questions. The best approach is heavily dependant on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @amof, I expected a difference but not as big! Regarding the design issues, what I can see is that all the queries and maintenance will be complicated a lot, so I'd try to avoid this and simplify it if possible. I would maybe look at some solutions made especially for this purpose, like XML databases... but I really can't recommend, don't have any experience with this use case. At least I'am glad to hear that the queries go fast now!