# MySQL tricky double / triple JOIN (?)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, social-networking

Table structure:

```
    users: uid, name
    friendships: uid1, uid2
    game_membership: gid, uid
```

basically I'm trying to get a query as a function of `gid`, and return:

```
uid1, name1, uid2, name2
```

where only the `uid`'s that are in the `game_membership` table under the given `gid` are returned. this is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT 
   f.uid1 AS id1, 
   u1.name AS name1, 
   f.uid2 AS id2, 
   u2.name AS name2
FROM 
   friendships AS f
WHERE 
   u1.uid in (SELECT uid FROM game_membership WHERE gid = <GID>)
   AND u2.uid in (SELECT uid FROM game_membership WHERE gid = <GID>)
JOIN users AS u1 ON f.uid1 = u1.uid
JOIN users AS u2 ON f.uid2 = u2.uid
```

I just get a MySQL syntax error right now. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I feel like maybe I have to do another JOIN or two on the `uid`'s in the `game_membership` table, one for each `uid`?

Comment: I believe you should join before your where clause

Comment: don't use the `where .. in (select)` construct - always learn to write it as a join! You will achieve [much better performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9982157/684229). See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you join to the Game_membership table instead of the where clause:

```
SELECT 
   f.uid1 AS id1, 
   u1.name AS name1, 
   f.uid2 AS id2, 
   u2.name AS name2
FROM 
   friendships AS f
JOIN game_membership AS user1_gm ON user1_gm.uid = f.uid1
JOIN game_membership AS user2_gm ON user2_gm.uid = f.uid2
JOIN users AS u1 ON f.uid1 = u1.uid
JOIN users AS u2 ON f.uid2 = u2.uid
WHERE user1_gm.gid = <GID> AND user2_gm.gid = <GID>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add joins to your *FROM* clause like this:

```
FROM friends f
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u1 ON f.uid1 = u1.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u2 on f.uid2 = u2.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
 SELECT 
   f.uid1 AS id1, 
   u1.name AS name1, 
   f.uid2 AS id2, 
   u2.name AS name2
FROM friendships AS f
INNER JOIN users AS u1 
   ON f.uid1 = u1.uid
INNER JOIN users AS u2 
   ON f.uid2 = u2.uid
INNER JOIN game_membership GMS
   ON GMS.UID=U1.UID
INNER JOIN game_membership GMS2
   ON GMS2.UID=U2.UID
WHERE 
   GMS.GID= <GID> and GMS2.GID=<GID>
```

and now it's not an alternative go with paul's :D

Comment: Two joins to `game_membership` are needed. Your `ON GMS.UID=U1.UID AND GMS.UID=U2.UID` seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
select uid1, u1.name as name1, uid2, u2.name as name2
from friendships 
    join game_membership as g1 on uid1 = g1.uid
    join game_membership as g2 on uid2 = g2.uid
    join users as u1 on uid1 = u1.uid
    join users as u2 on uid2 = u2.uid
where g1.gid = <GID> and g2.gid = <GID>
```